# Visual Studio Team Services (cloud) - Server Workspace

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have several of our projects at my company in source control using Visual Studio Team Services (visualstudio.com).  For the life of me I can't figure out how to get the workspace on my machine to flip to a Server workspace type.  We don't want multiple checkouts and we want to get latest when we edit a file, and server workspaces (as I understand it) are the only way to accomplish this.  Is it even possible to use server workspaces with the "cloud" version of TFS/Visual Studio Team Services?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  What does your server administrator have configured in Team Explorer -> Settings -> Team Project Collection -> Source Control -> Workspace Settings?

Comment: Does this change it for everyone or just for the server administrator's workspace?

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to your server with Visual Studio
2. Go to Team Explorer
3. Go to Settings

This part can be a little tricky so I attach a screen shot:

[image]

4. Under "Team Project Collection" go to Source Control
5. On the new dialog go to the second tab - Workspace Settings

So as you can see it is pretty obscure and I believe it is on purpose. By default the workspaces are of type "local" and these have their benefits. You may want to check out this article to make an informed decision: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx

Comment: See, that's what I thought too.  It's how I accomplished it when we had our own internal TFS server.  But now that I'm using Visual Studio Online for source control, it will tell me "Get latest on checkout is not supported in local workspaces. Checking out the local version." even when it is set to "Server" workspace.